# Interpret Repetition!

Tags: code-golf, math

*This challenge is the first in a two-challenge series about Repetition. The second will be up soon.*

In a language called Repetition (something I just made up), there consists an infinite string of `12345678901234567890...`, with `1234567890` repeating forever.

The following syntax is available to output numbers:

- `+-*/`: This inserts the operator into the string of repeating digits.

  - Examples:

    - `+` -> `1+2` = `3` (The `+` inserts a `+` between `1` and `2`)
    - `+*` -> `1+2*3` = `1+6` = `7` (Same as above, except two operators are used now)
    - `/` -> `1/2` = `0` (Repetition uses integer division)
    - `//` -> `1/2/3` = `0/3` = `0` (Repetition uses "left association" with multiple subtractions and divisions)
  - Each operator is inserted so that it has one digit to its left, unless there are `c`'s (see below).
- `c`: Concatenates with the next digit in the string.

  - Examples:

    - `c+` -> `12+3` = `15` (The `c` "continues" the `1` and concatenates it with the next digit, `2`, to form `12`)
    - `+c` -> `1+23` = `24`
    - `ccc` -> `1234`
- `()`: Brackets for processing numbers.

  - Examples:

    - `(c+)*` -> `(12+3)*4` = `15*4` = `60` (Repetition uses the order of operations)
    - `(c+)/c` -> `(12+3)/45` = `15/45` = `0`
    - `(cc+c)/` -> `(123+45)/6` = `168/6` = `28`
- `s`: Skip a number (removes the number from the infinite string).

  - `s+` -> `2+3` = `5` (`s` skips `1`)
  - `csc` -> `124` (The first `c` concats `1` and `2`, the `s` skips `3`, and the final `c` concats `12` to `4`)
  - `+s+` -> `7` (The first `+` adds `1` and `2` to make `3`, `s` skips `3`, and the final `+` adds `3` to `4` to make `7`)
  - `cs*(++)` -> `12*(4+5+6)` = `12*15` = `180`

In the examples above, only a finite amount of digits in the infinite string are used. The number of digits used is equivalent to `number of operators, concats and skips + 1`.

Your task is, when given a string of Repetition code, output the result.

Examples of input and output are:

```
++ -> 6
- -> -1
(-)* -> -3
cscc -> 1245
(cc+c)/ -> 28
cc+c/ -> 130
cs*(++) -> 180
```

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Specs:

- You are guaranteed that the result will never go above `2^31-1`.
- You are also guaranteed that the input will only consist of the symbols `+-*/cs()`.
- An empty program will output `1`.

Comment: What about the `~`s? Don't leave us hanging.

Comment: @RobertFraser Whoops, that was a mistake - c was originally ~, but it appears that I haven't fixed that completely.

Comment: Obviously directly after a `)` there shouldn't be a number in the resulting expression. Therefore. no `c` or `(` directly after `)` in the input. But can there be a `s` directly after `)` ? And likewise can there be a `s` just before `(` ?. I'd prefer only operators or string end just before or after `()`...

Comment: @TonHospel Ooh, you've got a good point there. The "s" symbol essentially removes the number it's associated with from the infinite string altogether, so it's a yes for both scenarios.

Comment: `cc+c/`=> `123+45/6` => `123+7` => `130`. Or did I miss something? (you wrote `52` in your examples)

Comment: @Dada Ah yeah, now that I think about it, I have no idea how I got 52. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: What's the output of `sc`? `23` as in `s+` or `13` as in `csc`?

Comment: @jimmy23013 `s` skips `1`, so the output would be `23`. (Also, how does `s+` output `23`?)

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp So it isn't possible to skip 2 and use c to output 13?

Comment: @jimmy23013 Yeah, as you can't `s` on the first one (because that would skip `1`), and you can't `c` (because then you have `12`).

Comment: The way  `s` works still seems strange.because it remains unclear in what state the digit sequence is left after each language element. What is the expression for `+s+` ? `1+2+4` or `1+3+4` ? `1+3+4` seems most logical, but then I would also expect `csc` to give `134` and not `124`

Comment: @TonHospel `+` adds `1` and `2`, `s` skips `3`, and `+` adds an additional `4`. The same goes for `c`: `c` concats `1` and `2` to become `12`, `s` skips `3`, and `c` concats `12` and `4` to become `124`. I should probably add those as examples.

Comment: So the `+` seems to consume the `2` so it's not there for `s` anymore. So how about `+(s)+` ? `1+(2)+4` or `1+(3)+4` ?

Comment: @TonHospel It doesn't make a difference. It's 1+(2)+4.

Comment: Ok, so `s` acts "late". That would however make me expect `1+3` for `s+` otherwise `s` at the start of the string will need special handling

Comment: Your specification however says `s+` is `2+3` as its first example. And still `s` keeps bugging me. I wonder how `+s()+` expands. If it is `1+(2)+4` then `(` comes before `2` but the `s` that comes even before the `(` seemingly still skips `3`, not `2`. If however the result is `1+(3)+4` then the effect of a `s` depends on what comes after it (compare it with `+s+`)

Comment: `sc` is `23` and `s+` is `1+3`? Does `s` skip the `1` now or the `2`? All examples use the first operation on operands `1` and `2` ... so `sc` should be `13`.

Comment: @Titus Sorry about that, s+ is 2+3.

Comment: Surely `// -> 1/2/3 = 0.5/3 = 6` is wrong. Wouldn’t it equal `0/3 = 0`?

Comment: @Lynn Ah yeah, sorry. I got confused with 3/0.5. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: **So what exactly happens with `+sc`??** If it's `1+34` then why isn't `+s+`=`1+3+4` (skipping before taking a digit), and if it's `1+24` then why isn't `sc`=`13` (skipping after taking a digit) and if it's `(1+2)4`=`34` then why isn't `+c`=`(1+2)3`=`33` (adding before concatenating).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 110 bytes

```
s=>eval((" "+s)[R='replace'](/[^\)](?!\()/g,x=>x+i++%10,i=1)[R](/c| (\ds)+|s\d/g,"")[R](/\d+\/\d+/g,"($&|0)"))
```

Very simple, but integer division adds 25 bytes. For some reason a regex in JS can't match both the beginning of a string and the first character, so that adds a few bytes as well.

#### How it works

1. Prepend a space to the input.
2. Append the next digit to each character (except `)`) that isn't immediately before a `(`.
3. Remove each `c`, a digit + `s` at the beginning (`1s2` -> `2`), and each `s` + a digit (`3s4` -> `3`).
4. Turn each division operation into int-division (`1/2` -> `(1/2|0)`).
5. Evaluate and return.

Comment: OK... your program has a bug... `ss+` returns `6`, when it's meant to return `7` (The two `s`'s skip `1` and `2`, so the `+` adds `3` and `4`).

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Something like `/^|,|$/g` will only match once at the beginning because both matches would have the same index. `$` doesn't have the same problem because the match has a greater index than any other possible match.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 332 bytes

```
@echo off
set s=
set e=
set d=
set r=
set/ps=
:d
set/ad=-~d%%10
:l
if "%s%"=="" goto g
set c=%s:~0,1%
set s=%s:~1%
if %c%==( set e=%e%(&goto l
if %c%==) set r=%r%)&goto l
if %c%==s goto d
if %c%==c set c=
if "%r%"=="" set/ar=d,d=-~d%%10
set e=%e%%r%%c%
set/ar=d
goto d
:g
if "%r%"=="" set/ar=d
cmd/cset/a%e%%r%
```

The behaviour of `s` makes this very awkward. (Maybe `cs` should evaluate to `13` and `-s` to `-2`?) Variables:

- `s` input string (explicitly blanked out because set/p doesn't change the variable if you don't input anything)
- `e` partial expression in normal integer arithmetic (which we can pass to `set/a` as a form of `eval`)
- `d` next digit from the infinite string of digits
- `r` right hand side of latest operator. We can't concatenate this immediately because `(` needs to come first, but we need to store it so that `s` won't increment it. Fortunately it does end up making the handling of `)` slightly easier.
- `c` current character.